# How the pattern ranking performed in this SDM paper?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, data-mining, ranking, sequential-pattern-mining

I am following this SDM paper "[Diversified Trajectory Pattern Ranking in Geo-Tagged Social Media](http://www.ifp.illinois.edu/~cao4/papers/sdm11_zyin.pdf)" that I found very intersting and inspiring.

However due to my limited knowledge in mathematical notations, I am having hard time understanding how their ranking module works. Their ranking method is as follows.

[image]

Mentioned below is a toy example that denotes how this raking method works.

[image]

I am mostly interested in how they got values for `Trajectories` section in the Table above in each iteration. It would be really great if someone could tell me how these values were derived.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.